# Using iptables to selectively route outgoing requests?

Tags: router, firewall, routing, dd-wrt, iptables

I'd like to set up my Dd-WRT firewall so that it uses the VPN service from a VPN provider to access a bunch of destinations and normal route foe all other requests.

In detail:

- giganews.com would be accessed thru VPN
  VyprVPN
- normal web sites such as amazon, ebay, et al thru transparent firewall.

I've run nito reading SOOOO many tutorials but I can't get to understand what the different entities are.

Any help?

Thxs

Answer (score 0):

Routing rules would be more appropriate than iptables for routing a small set of addresses to a particular interfaces.  You will need the add the appropriate `route add -net` specifications to due the routing.  You can route by name or IP address, but if the ipaddress changes, your routing will no longer hold.

If you want to use iptables, then I suggest you consider using Shorewall to build the iptables for you.  They will be quite complicated.  The [Shorewall MultiISP](http://www.shorewall.net/MultiISP.html) documentation should help understand the required configuration.

Answer (score 0):

See my question (and my own subsequent answer) here: [Setup routing and iptables for new VPN connection to redirect **only** ports 80 and 443](https://superuser.com/questions/354855/setup-routing-and-iptables-for-new-vpn-connection-to-redirect-only-ports-80)

If you substitute ports 80 and 443 for 119 then you should be good to go!