# Force certain applications to use VPN

Tags: linux, vpn, iptables

For a few days now, I've been trying to force only certain applications to use a VPN. I've thus far found it pretty simple to either force all applications to use it, or no applications to use it.

I'm not set on the script or anything. I just want this to work. Any of the following is acceptable:

- Force applications from a certain user to use the tun0 interface
- Force certain ports to use the tun0 interface
- Force specific processes to use the tun0 interface (this was my original intent but I understand this functionality hasn't existed in iptables for some time)

I'm not set on using routes/firewalls for the solution either, it's just most of the information I've managed to find seems to indicate that's the way to go.

I'm running Fedora and using OpenVPN.

I've been working with this script:

```
#!/bin/sh

DEV1=wlp0s20u2
IP1=192.168.0.200
GW1=192.168.0.1
TABLE1=internet
TABLE2=vpn
DEV2=tun0
IP2=`ifconfig | egrep -o '192.168.179.[0-9]{1,3}' | head -n1`
GW2=`ifconfig | egrep -o '192.168.179.[0-9]{1,3}' | tail -n1`

ip route flush table $TABLE1
ip route flush table $TABLE2
ip route show table main | grep -Ev ^default | while read ROUTE ; do
    ip route add table $TABLE1 $ROUTE
    ip route add table $TABLE2 $ROUTE
done
ip route add table $TABLE1 $GW1 dev $DEV1 src $IP1
# Error "RTNETLINK answers: File exists" at below line
ip route add table $TABLE2 $GW2 dev $DEV2 src $IP2
ip route add table $TABLE1 default via $GW1
ip route add table $TABLE2 default via $GW2

echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_dynaddr
echo "2" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/tun0/rp_filter

ip rule add from $IP1 lookup $TABLE1
ip rule add from $IP2 lookup $TABLE2
ip rule add fwmark 1 lookup $TABLE1
ip rule add fwmark 2 lookup $TABLE2

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $DEV1 -j SNAT --to-source $IP1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $DEV2 -j SNAT --to-source $IP2

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING           -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED          -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
iptables        -A OUTPUT               -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED          -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $DEV1  -m state --state NEW                          -j CONNMARK --set-mark 1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $DEV2  -m state --state NEW                          -j CONNMARK --set-mark 2
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING           -m connmark --mark 1                          -j MARK --set-mark 1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING           -m connmark --mark 2                          -j MARK --set-mark 2
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING           -m state --state NEW -m connmark ! --mark 0   -j CONNMARK --save-mark

# ADD PORTS HERE!
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i $DEV2 -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport  80 -j CONNMARK --set-mark 2
#iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i $DEV2 -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 443 -j CONNMARK --set-mark 2

route del default
route add default gw $GW1 $DEV1
```

altered slightly from one found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/354855/setup-routing-and-iptables-for-new-vpn-connection-to-redirect-only-ports-80).

This doesn't work. It gets traffic going to my wireless internet by default, but doesn't redirect traffic from port 80 to the VPN. The only hint I get is the mysterious

```
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
```

The point it occurs is marked within the script. I'm not sure what that means. I can prevent it by removing the loop shortly before the error occurs, but the script doesn't suddenly work if I do.

Help? I know a bit about networking/firewalls but this is *way* beyond my capabilities, and I frankly don't even know what about a third of that script even *does*.

Answer (score 1):

You can normally bind a network application to an IP:Port in its .conf file. You could add different IPs to each interface in your PC and then bind each application with a different IP, per instance you could have a mail server bound to IP 192.168.7.100 in the NIC card and some other applications bound to 192.168.7.101 in the tun0 interface.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but this question is specifically about some networking stuff on my laptop. I don't have any web services that need to use the VPN. As such, I need a more generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

Still any application that uses a network is bound to an interface/ip, it doesn't matter if it is a network service or a graphical client application if you can set the interface it will use you solved your problem, if not the packets will go through the predetermined interface.

Comment: Sure, but the tricky part is that by nature your computer wants to use *one* interface unless the destination is specifically only reachable by another. And most applications don't have an explicit option to select an interface. Moreover, the one application I found that *did* - my system's default torrent client, which doesn't need the VPN *anyway* - didn't even work! Try to envision me making, say, Firefox and only Firefox use the VPN. That is in fact what I'm trying to test before I implement it more generally. I do appreciate the attempt, though.